# Redirecting stderr in csh

Tags: linux, shell, csh, tcsh

I'm executing a program that dumps crash report into `STDERR` from where I have to filter some necessary information. The problem is that I'm unable to redirect `STDERR` to `STDOUT` and `PIPE` it with `grep`

```
command 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep "^[^-]" >& /tmp/fl
```

Getting error: `Ambiguous output redirect.`

Same command works under bash terminal.
What should I change to make it work ?

Comment: See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/134358/288136).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`csh` is significantly more limited than bash when it comes to file redirection. In `csh`, you can redirect `stdout` with the usual `>` operator, you can redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` with the `>&` operator, you can pipe `stdout` and `stderr` with the `|&` operator, but there is no single operator to redirect `stderr` alone.

The usual workaround is to execute the command in a sub-shell, redirecting `stdout` in that sub-shell to whatever file you want (`/dev/null` in this case), and then use the `|&` operator to redirect `stdout` and `stderr` of the sub-shell to the next command in the main shell.

In your case, this means something like:

```
( command >/dev/null ) |& grep "^[^-]" >&/tmp/fl
```

Because `stdout` is redirected to `/dev/null` inside the sub-shell, the `|&` operator will end up acting as `2>&1` in bash - since `stdout` is discarded in the sub-shell, nothing written to `stdout` will ever reach the pipe.

Comment: I thought the usual workaround was to invoke `sh`: `sh -c "command 2>&1 > /dev/null"`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yeah, sure. I assumed he wants to remain in csh for some reason.

Answer (score 7):

If you dont mind mixing stdout and stderr into the pipe you can use

```
command |& grep "^[^-]" >& /tmp/fl
```

Otherwise you can do the hack:

```
(command >/dev/null) |& grep "^[^-]" >& /tmp/fl
```

which separates out stdout to null, then piping stdout and stderr just gives
stderr as content.